# Multiple column HTML Table From Single Column Text File In PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple working PHP script to write an HTML table from a text file that contains a single column of data that contains HTML links. This writes the data horizontally in a row across 5 or 6 columns as I want it to. But I am looking to set up a script with a loop that will take this list of data and input it into the table until it finishes the data list, so that I do not have to hard code each table cell individually. Just let the script create each table cell, at 5 or 6 columns across (whichever I need for this specific table), go to the next row, etc., until it runs out of data. The data in the data file will be added to on a regular basis, so the table will not be of a certain fixed length forever. I am using the echo command so that I can add some more HTML formatting later on.

Even though my existing script is simple and it works, if you can think of a better way of doing what I am trying to do, all suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Stan...

PHP code follows:

```
    <?php
    $item = @fopen('linklist.txt', "r");

    if ($item) { while (!feof($item)) { $lines[] = fgets($item, 4096); } fclose($item); }

    echo'
    <TABLE border="1">
    <TR>

    <TD>'.($lines[1]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[2]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[3]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[4]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[5]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[6]).'</td>
    </tr>
    <TR>
    <TD>'.($lines[7]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[8]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[9]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[10]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[11]).'</td>
    <TD>'.($lines[12]).'</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- And So On, And So On, ETC -->

    </table>'

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo '<table border="1"><tr>';
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($lines); $i++) {
    echo '<td>'.$lines[$i].'</td>';
    if(($i+1)%6==0 && $i!=sizeof($lines)-1) echo '</tr><tr>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

**Explanation:**

Repeats through each "line" and writes the `<td>value</td>`

If a line is a multiple of 6, after writing the value, then close the row, and open another (unless it's the last one, since it will close the row after the loop as well.

(I assume you meant to start on `$line[0]`, but if you really meant to start on `$line[1]`, just change the `$i=0;` to `$i=1;`, remove the `+1` in the row check, and change `$i<sizeof` to `$i<=sizeof`

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry that I did not get back to you sooner but other things take over my time sometimes. Your answer worked out great, and was easy to understand. I even did modify the process a little further, using fgetcsv instead of fgets so as to use this with a multi column csv file (but still using only one of the data columns to print a table), instead of the original single column that I started out with. Just curious, why did you edit your answer to take out the complete working code, compared to the current answer that does not load the file? Thanks again, Stan

Comment: Stan - I removed the part of your code that I didn't change.  Figured it wasn't necessary to repeat, and made the answer easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines = chunk_split($lines,6);
?>
<TABLE border="1">
<? foreach ($lines as $row): ?>
  <TR>
  <? foreach ($row as $value): ?>
    <TD><?=$value?></td> 
  <? endforeach ?>
  <TR>
<? endforeach ?>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Hi Col., Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry that I did not get back to you sooner but other things take over my time sometimes. In trying your code, I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' " in the line "<TD><?=$value<?>/td>, which does not have any ";" in it?? Thanks for you reply though, Stan

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code...

```
x = 0
echo '<TABLE border="1">'
For each $line in $lines {
  x = x + 1
  if x = 1 {
    echo '<TR>'
  }
  echo <TD>'.($line).'</TD>
  if x = 6 {
    echo '</TR>'
    x = 0
  }
}
echo '</TABLE>'
```

Note the use of the $line object to hold the value of the $line array element.

hth

Comment: Hi Mophilly, Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry that I did not get back to you sooner but other things take over my time sometimes. Sorry, but I am new here and do not understand the term "pseudo code". Thanks anyway for your reply, Stan

Comment: Psuedo code means that the example is algorithmically correct (hopefully) but not expressed in a specific programming syntax (or "language" if you prefer). BTW, your lack of understanding an industry standard term, e.g. psuedo code, should not result in a down vote on my comment.

Comment: Hi Mophilly, It has been a while since I last visited this question, but I do not believe that I was the one who gave you the down vote. (I may be mistaken, but at least I don't think I did.) I don't like this system of down votes on this board just because someone doesn't like something about what someone else said. It seems to breed an air of snootieness. I do not give out down votes especially to someone who has tried to help me. Just like someone gave me a down vote on my original question for whatever reason??? If someone has a gripe, I think that they should be required to give a reason.

Comment: Mophilly, I ran out of room in my last rant. Just wanted to thank you again for your help...Stan...

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, Stan. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a loop, you can also avoid reading the complete file into memory, which might be beneficial:

```
<?php

$item = @fopen('linklist.txt', "r");
if ($item) {
  echo'<TABLE border="1">';
  $i=0;
  $lines=array();
  while (!feof($item)) { 
    $line[] = fgets($item, 4096);
    $i++;
    if ($i==6) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo '<TD>'.($lines[0]).'</td>';
      echo '<TD>'.($lines[1]).'</td>';
      echo '<TD>'.($lines[2]).'</td>';
      echo '<TD>'.($lines[3]).'</td>';
      echo '<TD>'.($lines[4]).'</td>';
      echo '<TD>'.($lines[5]).'</td>';
      echo "<tr>";
      $i=0;
      $lines=array();
    }
  }
  echo '</table>';
  fclose($item); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi Eugen, Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry that I did not get back to you sooner but other things take over my time sometimes. For some strange reason though with your code, all I get is a blank table with no data. Thanks anyway for your thoughts and reply, Stan